# I cannot format a row copied from one sheet to another as string in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am having trouble when copying a row from one sheet to another in the same Excel file. Some cells contain large numbers, which creates a problem when copying them because they get rounded up and I don't want that to happen. I heard I can overcome that problem by pasting them as a string, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696191/phpexcel-set-cells-as-string-while-uploading-from-array). But no matter what I do the values of the cells are still formatted as numbers, which messes up the whole process.

Can you please help me? Thanks!

Excerpt code:

```
//por ultimo lo demas
    for($i=2; $i<$rowCount;$i++){
        $order = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getValue();
        if($order != 'xxx'){
            $cellValues = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray("A$i:AP$i", null, true, true, false);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
            PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder(new PHPExcel_Cell_MyColumnValueBinder($cellValues));
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($cellValues, null, 'A'.$newRow);
            $newRow++;
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$i, 'xxx');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think that passing the cell values to `PHPExcel_Cell_MyColumnValueBinder()` is correct? The page you've linked passes an array of column addresses that should be treated as string data (`PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder(new PHPExcel_Cell_MyColumnValueBinder(['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F']));`), not values from cells

Comment: It was all I found. I wanted to try it out since nothing seemed to work

Comment: And unless you have different rules for every row, you don't need to set the binder for every row; just set it once before the loop

Comment: @MarkBaker the only rule I want is for it to be displayed as String. That's all

Comment: For what to be displayed as string? Which columns? If it's every column, then modify that binder code so it treats every value as string without needing to check columns at all

Comment: Every single cell (for ease).

Comment: Then write a binder that just does `$cell->setValueExplicit((string) $value, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING); return true;`